# How to apply LookAndFeel of JTatto in java Frames

Tags: java, swing, themes, look-and-feel, classcastexception

I am trying to implement look and feel in JFrame swing java, its throwing following  exception

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException:javax.swing.DebugGraphics cannot be cast to java.awt.Graphics2D "
```

Its working on some forms. what is the reason for above error

Comment: be sure that nobody knows based on / from this description, exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though pretty much the whole context is missing, I have something to point out.

Ever since Java 1.4 or so, all `Graphics` objects passed between `paint`, `paintComponent`, `paintBackground`, `paintChildren` and whatnot became, in fact, `Graphics2D` objects. This is widely considered as fact (`Graphics` == `Graphics2D`).

However, some of your components seem to be using 
[setDebugGraphicsOptions(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDebugGraphicsOptions%28int%29). This DOES make it so the former 'fact' is no longer true. As long as you have a robust implementation (such as `instanceof Graphics2D` checks), you will notice that, for example, `RenderingHints` (only available on `Graphics2D`) are no longer applied when using debug graphics.
Otherwise, it will fail with the exact exception you are getting.

It would appear all your code assumes that `Graphics` are `Graphics2D`. So you have to either stop using graphic debug options, or manually fix all overridden `paintComponent` methods.